# How do I pass a Context to r.WithContext while retaining values of the original request context?

Tags: go

## Problem statement

I want to tie the lifetime of an HTTP request to a context that was created outside the scope of the web application.  Thus, I wrote the following middleware (using `github.com/go-chi/chi`):

```
func BindContext(c context.Context) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(c))
        })
    }
}
```

The middleware is used in the following minimal test case:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/SentimensRG/ctx"
    "github.com/SentimensRG/ctx/sigctx"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
)

func greet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}

func BindContext(c context.Context) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(c))
        })
    }
}

func main() {
    r := chi.NewMux()
    r.Use(BindContext(ctx.AsContext(sigctx.New())))
    r.Get("/", greet)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

The handler panics with the following error:

```
2018/07/25 14:58:57 http: panic serving [::1]:56527: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not *chi.Context
goroutine 35 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc42014a0a0)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1726 +0xd0
panic(0x12749c0, 0xc42014c200)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:502 +0x229
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*Mux).routeHTTP(0xc4201180c0, 0x12fcf00, 0xc420166000, 0xc420160200)
        /Users/lthibault/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/mux.go:400 +0x2f3
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*Mux).(github.com/go-chi/chi.routeHTTP)-fm(0x12fcf00, 0xc420166000, 0xc420160200)
        /Users/lthibault/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/mux.go:368 +0x48
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc420142010, 0x12fcf00, 0xc420166000, 0xc420160200)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1947 +0x44
main.fail.func1.1(0x12fcf00, 0xc420166000, 0xc420160100)
        /Users/lthibault/go/src/github.com/lthibault/mesh/cmd/scratch/main.go:22 +0x77
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc420148000, 0x12fcf00, 0xc420166000, 0xc420160100)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1947 +0x44
github.com/go-chi/chi.(*Mux).ServeHTTP(0xc4201180c0, 0x12fcf00, 0xc420166000, 0xc420160000)
        /Users/lthibault/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/mux.go:81 +0x221
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc420150000, 0x12fcf00, 0xc420166000, 0xc420160000)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2694 +0xbc
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc42014a0a0, 0x12fd1c0, 0xc42014c080)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1830 +0x651
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2795 +0x27b
```

## Inelegant solution

The problem appears to come from [Mux.routeHTTP](https://github.com/go-chi/chi/blob/master/mux.go#L400), where an attempt is made to recover a `*chi.Context` from `r.Context()`.  It would appear that `r.WithContext` does not transfer values stored in the request context to the new context.

The obvious (albeit ugly) fix is:

```
func BindContext(c context.Context) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            rctx := r.Context().Value(chi.RouteCtxKey).(*chi.Context)
            c = context.WithValue(c, chi.RouteCtxKey, rctx)
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(c))
        })
    }
}
```

This works, but leaves me feeling uneasy.  Do I really need to manually transfer each relevant value from `r.Context()` into the context being passed to `r.WithContext()`?

There are several failure cases, here:

- What happens when there are many different values to be transferred?
- What happens when the context keys aren't exported (as is recommended in Go)?
- What happens if the original context terminates before the one I passed in?

(In few words:  nothing good!)

## My question is as follows

Is there a standard "merge" a context passed to `r.WithContext` with the exiting context in `r.Context`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though there is no out-of-the-box solution for this, but `github.com/SentimensRG/ctx` provides a `mergectx` subpackage specifically for this purpose.

The solution is to use [`mergectx.Merge`](https://godoc.org/github.com/SentimensRG/ctx/mergectx#Mergehttps://godoc.org/github.com/SentimensRG/ctx/mergectx#Merge).

Answer (score 1):

You should not replace the context on incoming request with an unrelated context. For starters:

> Package context defines the Context type, which carries deadlines, cancelation signals, and other request-scoped values across API boundaries and between processes.

`sigctx.New()` is called before any request happens and is therefore by definition not request scoped. Pretty much all code expects the request context to be canceled when a) the request finishes, or b) the client aborts the request (usually because it is no longer interested in the response). You are breaking that assumption by replacing the context. You are also removing any values that other middlewares may have added to the context earlier.

It seems like you wish to abort requests on SIGINT or SIGTERM. You should *add* that cancelation condition to the request context instead of replacing it completely. Perhaps like so:

```
func BindContext(c context.Context) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
                return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                        rCtx := r.Context()
                        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(rCtx)

                        go func() {
                                select {
                                case <-c.Done(): // SIGINT/SIGTERM
                                case <-rCtx.Done(): // Request finished or client aborted
                                }
                                cancel()
                        }()

                        h.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
                })
        }
}
```

Update:

To let users configure the context, accept a function that derives a new context from the request context (although users might as well supply a middleware that does this directly):

```
func WithContext(new func(context.Context) context.Context) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            r = r.WithContext(new(r.Context()))

            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })  
    }   
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question.  The issue here is that I want the context passed to `BindContext` to be user-configurable.  I can't know ahead of time what kind of context will be passed in.  Informally, the requirement here is to somehow "merge" two contexts (which I naively assumed was what `r.WithContext` achieved).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and was able to resolve this by creating the new context using [chi.NewRouteContext](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-chi/chi#NewRouteContext).

The request is being made using `httptest`. You can update the request its context using `r.WithContext`.

**Example**

```
w := httptest.NewRecorder()
r := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)

rctx := chi.NewRouteContext()
rctx.URLParams.Add("key", "value")

r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), chi.RouteCtxKey, rctx))

handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    key := chi.URLParam(r, "key") // "value"
}

handler(w, r)
```

See the folling Gist from aapolkovsky: https://gist.github.com/aapolkovsky/1375348cab941e36c62da24a32fbebe7